# Making sure windows responds to key strokes

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way of making sure a program responds to a key stroke sent from AutoHotkey before sending another one? I want to send key strokes as quickly as possible, but the problem is that it takes some time for some menus/windows/etc. to appear, so I seem to need to specify a key delay and use `Send`, or alternatively use `Sleep` (meaning it likely won't be "as quickly as possible"), because otherwise AutoHotkey might send the keys *too soon* and in turn maybe do something you didn't want to.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're actually doing. What effect are these keystrokes supposed to have? Are you inserting text? Or do you want to trigger functions/navigate in some kind of menu? In order to determine if the target window has processed your input, something has to change. There are multiple things that can change (e.g. window title, control text, msgbox popups etc.). Maybe the program even generates some other form of output (e.g. writing files/registry entries). But that's all a long shot as long as you don't let us in on what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could just send all the keystrokes at once.  You CAN send an entire string, you know.

However, if the window is already active and you can send one keystroke to it, chances are you shouldn't have any problem sending more as long as the window hasn't lost focus between keystrokes.

You can also try using `sendinput` instead of just `send` if the window doesn't seem receptive to `send`.

On my computer, I have set <kbd>win+space</kbd> to send this line of dashes as one string and it does it in a fraction of a second:  `-------------------------------------------------------------------`

Another option is to paste a string instead of sending keystrokes.  Just use `send ^v` to paste the contents of a variable.  That is much faster than using `send` to send a string of characters, but you need to make sure your window is able to receive paste commands.

I say these things because it may not be necessary to check at all.  You can be assured that the key is being sent - that's what ahk is supposed to do, you know.

The only way you could possibly get confirmation is if you are sending to an edit control and can fetch back the text you sent.

There is no way to confirm that a menu has received keystrokes.  You just have to test it until it works right.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The important question is how I can check if a window performed the action it's supposed to after a key press, not just how I can plainly send keys the quickest. In my particular case, I'd like to send keys to newly opened windows or menus, so there likely has to be something that waits for that to happen. I guess what I'm wondering is if AHK has any built-in function that does that.

Comment: Are you sending keystrokes to a gui from the same script or to an external window?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out the following commands:
[ControlSend](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm)/[ControlClick](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) and [ControlGet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm)/[ControlGetText](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGetText.htm)
The first two allow you to directly set text/options in specific controls and the last two allow you to read what text/option is currently set in a specific control.